# Binding Error in runtime clearing ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection that works perfectly, but I can't remove a binding error that appears in runtime when I clear this ObservableCollection:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=Icon; DataItem='NamedObject' (HashCode=40835417); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
```

I made a small code to reproduce my problem that I show below: (View):

```
    <Button Height="40" Width="40" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Height="32" Source="{Binding Icon}" Stretch="Fill" Width="32"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Description}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

---

```
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList { get; set; }

    public void TestList()
    {
        ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        ProductList.Add(new Product("Product1", "pack://application:,,,/Product1.png"));
        ProductList.Add(new Product("Product2", "pack://application:,,,/Product2.png"));
        ProductList.Add(new Product("Product3", "pack://application:,,,/Product3.png"));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         ProductList.Clear();          
         ProductList.Add(new Product("Product4", "pack://application:,,,/Product4.png"));            
    }
```

And my product class:

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region "## INotifyPropertyChanged Members ##"
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { this._propertyChanged += value; }
        remove { this._propertyChanged -= value; }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            if (this._propertyChanged != null)
                this._propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        });
    }
    #endregion

    public string Description
    {
        get { return this.description; }
        set
        {
            this.description = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }
    private string description;

    public BitmapImage Icon
    {
        get { return this.icon; }
        set
        {
            this.icon = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Icon");
        }
    }
    private BitmapImage icon;

    public Product(string desc, string iconPath)
    {
        Description = desc;
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(iconPath));
        bi.Freeze();
        Icon = bi;
    }
}
```

---

The error appears when I click the button and the following line is executed:
             ProductList.Clear();

I have done many tests:

- Individually delete items from the list
- Use a Fallback and TargetNullValue:

  ```
     <Image Height="32" Source="{Binding Icon, FallbackValue='pack://application:,,,/transparent.png', TargetNullValue='pack://application:,,,/transparent.png'}" Stretch="Fill" Width="32"/>
  ```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try ProductList.ClearItems()?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654925(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm able to clear the product list with no problem. The error does not reproduce.

Comment: Your implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` looks a little messy, and it may not even be necessary, unless you're going to dynamically change the description and / or icon for individual products in your list.

Comment: The ".Clear()" function works only that returns me the annoying runtime error in the binding.
INotifyPropertyChanged may not be necessary in the example, but it does not affect the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the TargetNullValue, and FallbackValue and see if it still occurs? If it does not there is a problem with your URI to the file.

Also keep in mind if you are referencing transparent.png often you are loading the same image into memory many times. Instead consider adding a line to your ResourceDictionary like so:

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="/MyApp;component/Images/transparent.png" x:Key="Transparent" PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" />
```

Then using in the XAML like so:

```
<Image Height="32" Source="{Binding Icon, FallbackValue={StaticResource:Transparent}, TargetNullValue={StaticResource:Transparent}" Stretch="Fill" Width="32"/>
```

This change will load your image once but use it many places decreasing memory pressure.

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion, it is very useful. Anyway the error persists.